# Using a mouse and keyboard with Splatoon 2; Banable offence?

Tags: splatoon-2

Is it a banable offence to use a mouse and keyboard. It is possible; you can see a demo here:

Comment: Also instructions on how to do it are here if your interested:
https://youtu.be/tjjbWJ_VHFs

Comment: As a rule of thumb - if you need to ask, the answer is probably yes

Comment: Well if it is banable what rule am I breaking to get baned?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a mouse and keyboard is not a banable offence, but it is considered "cheating" by many as it gives you an unfair advantage over other players. It's harder on the Switch because you have to keep the controller steady to keep looking in the same direction, but on the computer, you can fidget all you want.

Comment: Just an addendum; this is not exclusive to the Switch.  In any twitch game (twitch meaning it's largely reflex based), someone using keyboard and mouse has a clear advantage due to enhanced and customizable precision and reaction time. This is why some games with team or competitive online play allow lobbies to define allowed controls in matchmaking.